# Is there a way to copy my VS Code Snippet string via Pyperclip

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, clipboard, pyperclip

I'm trying to get a Python script that will take code from my clipboard and format it to be a VS Code snippet, finally place it back on my clipboard (via Pyperclip).

I want to escape

- Backslashes (\)
- Quotes (")

I want to replace

- Actual tabs with (\t)

Input:

```py
import pyperclip
string = """def print_string():
    print("YOLO\n")
"""
x = string.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("\"","\\\"").replace("\t","\\t")
pyperclip.copy(x)
```

Actual Output:
(Pasting from the clipboard)

```
def print_string():
    print(\"YOLO
\")
```

Expected Output:
(What would be ok to almost immediately be used in the body of a VS Code snippet)

```
def print_string():
\tprint(\"YOLO\\n\")
```

How do I get what I'm missing, encoding it a certain way?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to precede the string quotation marks with the letter r to represent the original string and avoid backslash escaping in the string. Like this:

```
string = r"""def print_string():
    print("YOLO\n")
"""
```

For more explanations, please refer to the official documentation.
[String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Comment: Ok so this was just my example. I will really be getting my string variable out of my clipboard. I would have to raw encode it then, is: 
```string.encode('unicode_escape')```
What you would be looking for to do that?

Comment: You just need to add the letter R before the three quotation marks, then it works, it's a built-in syntax of python.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it working, not using Bruce's method....below is my code:

`

```
import pyperclip
string = pyperclip.paste()
my_list = []
for x in string.split("\r\n"):
    my_string = x.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("\"","\\\"").replace("\t","\\t").replace("    ", "\\t")
    my_list.append(f"\"{my_string}\",")
value = "\n".join(my_list)
pyperclip.copy(value)
```

`